Next js ecommerce application manage cart issue
I am developing one ecommerce application with frontend as next.js and backend using java spring boot.
  now i need to manage cart on front side. so, which is the best place on client(browser) side to store cart items.
  as, earlier i had used localstorage but it is giving issue localstorage undefined for nexjs application.

can someone from ecommerce expertise can help to give me some suggestions where i can store cart information.
 so, i will not have any issue from next.js side and i can deploy it
